# I need to filter Titles by genre field, I tried to use DjangoFilterBackend, but it didn't work, I don't know, how to create a CustomSearchFilter?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need to filter Titles by genre field, I tried to use DjangoFilterBackend, but it didn't work, I don't know, how to create a CustomSearchFilter?

Views:

```
class GenreViewSet(ModelCVDViewSet):
    queryset = Genre.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GenreSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAdminOrReadOnly,)
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, filters.SearchFilter)
    filterset_fields = ('name', 'slug')
    search_fields = ('name', 'slug')
    lookup_field = 'slug'


class TitleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Title.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TitleSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAdminOrReadOnly,)
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, filters.SearchFilter)
    filterset_fields = ('genre__slug', 'category__slug', 'name', 'year')
    search_fields = ('=genre__slug', '=category__slug', 'name', 'year')
```

Comment: Could you show the code of Title model and the filter that you created?

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, i already found a solution, needed to use FilterSet :)

Comment: Post here, please. Then your question can be declared as solved and closed and may help others.

Answer (score 0):

To TitleViewSet was added filterset_class:

```
class TitleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Title.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TitleSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAdmin | ReadOnly]
    filterset_class = TitleFilter

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Title.objects.all().annotate(rating=Avg('reviews__score'),)
```

Where TitleFilter:

```
class TitleFilter(FilterSet):
    name = CharFilter(field_name='name', lookup_expr='icontains')
    category = CharFilter(field_name='category__slug')
    genre = CharFilter(field_name='genre__slug')
    year = NumberFilter(field_name='year')

    class Meta:
        model = Title
        fields = ['name', 'category', 'genre', 'year']
```